# GUI archive manager that works well over ssh

Tags: software-rec, archive

I'm using `file-roller` and it doesn't work well when my archive file is accessed via ssh (it throws an error when I try to open it). Any alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access remote files using `fish://` or `sftp://` with every KDE application. For example you can connect to the remote host using file managers like Dolphin or Konqueror and after that every file that you click will be open (in KDE app) like it was file on your local drive. Archives will be opened in Ark (KDE archive manager). And of course you can open archives directly in Ark (`File -> Open -> sftp://remotehost/path/to/file`)...

Another alternative that I know, that it works is Emacs... ;) But before you try it you should look at [Emacs learning curve](http://bc.tech.coop/blog/images/curves.jpg)... ;)

Answer (score 4):

It Works For Me™. Gnome applications have built-in support for file access over ssh through [Gvfs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gvfs) (formerly [Gnome-VFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GnomeVFS)).

Another way to access files over ssh is [sshfs](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html). It requires an OS that supports [FUSE](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/), but most unices (Linux, Mac OS X, *BSD, Solaris, …) do these days. Since the files are presented through the ordinary filesystem interface, no specific application support is required. I don't know if there's a GUI wrapper for it; the command-line workflow is

```
mkdir ~/example.com
sshfs example.com:/path/to/directory ~/example.com
file-roller ~/example.com/foo.zip
# ...
fusermount -u ~/example.com
```

Comment: Do you mean you can open such an archive file over ssh? You can also extract it?

Comment: @Tshepang: On Ubuntu 10.04, if I navigate to `sftp://host/path/to/directory` in Nautilus, then click on a `tar.gz` file, the archive is opened in `file-roller`. I can then extract it in a local directory or in a directory on the remote host. I haven't tried other combinations.

Comment: I guess it's a bug in Debian Squeeze then. Thanks.